# How do you dynamically nest/embed component Templates in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-components

Plunkr Link to what I'm trying to do -> https://plnkr.co/edit/mC8jGYROlpqFpnjTCQKr?p=preview

My goal is to be able to drag something from the tools menu to the left onto the stage. upon "drop" the selected item should be nested within the stage.

I've searched the documentation an blogs. I've seen that the "CreateEmbeddedView" seems like what I'm supposed to use.

according to the Angular2 documentation, the following is what I'm looking for:

> createEmbeddedView(templateRef: TemplateRef, context?: C, index?: number) : EmbeddedViewRef

however can't seem to find a practical example of this. what I've resorted to using is the following in "src/designer-droppable.directive.ts":

```
addWidget(textWidget: { new(): TextWidget }): ComponentRef<TextWidget>{
    let dialogComponentFactory = 
      this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(textWidget);

    let dialogComponentRef = this.viewContainer.createComponent(dialogComponentFactory, this.viewContainer.length);
    //let tw = TemplateRef<{new(): TextWidget}>;
    //let dialogComponentRef = this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(TemplateRef<new() => TextWidget>);

    return dialogComponentRef;
}
```

however, this adds a component as a sibling to "viewContainerRef" rather than embedding it. i.e. in the plnkr, if you drag something onto the stage it is added to the Right of the stage rather than being embedded.

I've tried to use CreateEmbeddedView, but I am unclear as to how to define the TemplateRef dynamically.

I've seen a lot of outdated documentation around Dynamic Component Loader which has since been deprecated in favor of the Factories. Any assistance in what I'm missing would be great. any live examples would be wonderful.

thank you.